# how to fix select and update to the same table

Tags: mysql, select

```
update moodlesocialuser 
set moodlesocialuser.deleted=deleted+1 
where id IN (
  select m1.id 
  from moodlesocialuser m1 
  join moodlesocialpost m2 on m1.id=m2.userid 
  where m2.module='blog' 
  and m1.deleted='0' 
  and url like 'http%' 
  and m1.id NOT IN (
    select id from moodlesocialcourse_display
  ) 
);
```

I can't do an update and select from the same table.

> ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'moodlesocialuser' for update in FROM clause.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please take your time formatting the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says, that you're trying to update the table you're reading from.

Use a temporary table:

```
create temporary table foo (id int);

insert into foo 
  select m1.id 
  from moodlesocialuser m1 
  join moodlesocialpost m2 on m1.id=m2.userid 
  where m2.module='blog' 
  and m1.deleted='0' 
  and url like 'http%' 
  and m1.id NOT IN (
    select id from moodlesocialcourse_display
  ) 
;

update moodlesocialuser m
inner join foo on m.id = foo.id
set m.deleted=deleted+1 
;

drop table foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using group by clause if there is no aggregate function in this query.
Comment out that group by clause and script will run without any error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you copy-pasted an existing query in that UPDATE statement. You can get rid of the m1 alias in the first subquery, like this maybe :

```
update moodlesocialuser 
set moodlesocialuser.deleted=deleted+1 
where id IN (
  select m2.userid
  where m2.module='blog' 
  and url like 'http%'
)
and moodlesocialuser.deleted='0' 
and id NOT IN (
    select id from moodlesocialcourse_display
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify table you are selecting from [(read more here)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html); on the other hand, i think you can get rid of that subquery, like this(i don't think that query bellow will actually work, you better test it on not-valuable data; what i'm trying to say - that you can join in update too):

```
UPDATE moodlesocialuser mu, moodlesocialcourse_display md, moodlesocialpost mp
SET mu.deleted=mu.deleted + 1 
WHERE
md.id != mu.id AND
mu.deleted = 0 AND
mp.userid = mu.id AND
mp.module = 'blog' AND
mp.url LIKE 'http%'
```